# With incremental compilation and changed files `compilation-goto-error` moves to wrong line

Tags: compilation

I work on a typescript project that I compile with `webpack serve`, using `projectile-run-project`. My `*compilation` buffer shows the webpack output, which includes typescript errors. After some webpack hacking, I managed to get the errors into a `compilation` mode compatible format. When I select an error (which runs `compilation-goto-error` on this error), emacs opens the respective file in another buffer and jumps to the correct line. This works well so far.

When I change files, `webpack serve` immediately recompiles the project, and echos new error messages into `*compilation*`.

When I now edit a file, emacs seems to memorise error locations *at the start* of the compilation. Meaning:

- I start compilation
- I edit file `index.ts` to add a new line after line 4
- webpack reports an error at `index.ts:6`
- `compile-goto-error` goes to `index.ts:7`

I assume that this happens because `compilation` mode knows that line 6 in `index.ts` at the start of the compilation is now at line 7. However, I don't need that memoization, as the compilation reports current (correct) lines. How can I make `compilation-goto-error` use current lines, not cached onces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I was just finishing writing my answer I found what I think might be a solution.

I had a look at `compile.el`, and I found several messages relating to `omake -P`, which probably has a similar re-compilation behaviour. [An entry into `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` omake](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0445720b75edc8ff06074750512ade3d0e667575/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L443) calls `compilation--flush-file-structure` for the respective file, so that the memoisation is cleared prior to navigating there:

```lisp
    (omake
     ;; "omake -P" reports "file foo changed"
     ;; (useful if you do "cvs up" and want to see what has changed)
     "^\\*\\*\\* omake: file \\(.*\\) changed" 1 nil nil nil nil
     ;; FIXME-omake: This tries to prevent reusing pre-existing markers
     ;; for subsequent messages, since those messages's line numbers
     ;; are about another version of the file.
     (0 (progn (compilation--flush-file-structure (match-string 1))
               nil)))
```

I adopted this for the `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` entries for typescript, using [a bit from `typescript-mode.el`](https://github.com/emacs-typescript/typescript.el/blob/1043025d42602d560949955410d3afa2562130ee/typescript-mode.el#L2798):

```lisp
;; handle plain compiler-errors like the following when doing M-x compile<ret>tsc<ret>
;;
;; greeter.ts(24,9): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
;; greeter.ts(30,12): error TS2339: Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'number'.
(defconst typescript-tsc-error-regexp
  (concat
   "^[[:blank:]]*"
   "\\([^(\r\n)]+\\)(\\([0-9]+\\),\\([0-9]+\\)):[[:blank:]]+"
   "error [[:alnum:]]+: [^\r\n]+$")
  "Regexp to match errors generated by tsc.")
```

I add the result to `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`, overiding the regular `typescript-mode` entries:

```lisp
(dolist
    (regexp
     `((typescript-tsc
        ,typescript-tsc-error-regexp
        1 2 3 2
        ;; for flushing the marker cache of this file
        nil (0 (progn (compilation--flush-file-structure (match-string 1))
                      nil)))

       (typescript-tsc-pretty
        ,typescript-tsc-pretty-error-regexp
        1 2 3 2
        ;; for flushing the marker cache of this file
        nil (0 (progn (compilation--flush-file-structure (match-string 1))
                      nil)))))
  (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist regexp)
  (add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist (car regexp)))
```

That feels *really* hackish, but so far seems to work.